# Reports per webpage and per logged in user in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is this possible to achieve in Google Analytics:

- a separate report for the selected page in the website
- this report will contain the list of users logged in the website, who visited this page, and for every user there will be:

  - user id, allowing to match this user with the website users
  - duration and date of the visit
  - geolocation, browser, etc. as collected by GA

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom report like this, with the relevant dimensions and filtered by the page path that you want:

[image]

Note that you only have up to 5 dimensions for custom reports, so you may not get everything you want within the report.

Comment: Or you can do it by https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/ . Then you've got up to 7 dims